# Is this the best way to merge two dicts of dicts together and sum similar values

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models

Is there a faster or more "pythonic" way to achieve that:

```
dicta = {'a':{'a1':1, 'a2':2}, 'b':{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2}}
dictb = {'b':{'b1':1, 'a2':2}, 'c':{'c1': 1, 'c2': 2}}
dictc = {}

dictc.update(dicta)
for outside_key in dictb:
    if outside_key in dictc:
        for inside_key in dictb[outside_key]:
            if inside_key in dictc[outside_key]:
                dictc[outside_key][inside_key] += dictb[outside_key][inside_key]
            else:
                dictc[outside_key][inside_key] = dictb[outside_key][inside_key]
    else:
        dictc[outside_key] = dictb[outside_key]
```

dictc now contains the following:

```
{'a': {'a1': 1, 'a2': 2},
 'c': {'c2': 2, 'c1': 1},
 'b': {'a2': 2, 'b1': 2, 'b2': 2}}
```

I'm using this in a django model definition, the above seemed the most obvious way to describe the problem but I then realised that it was not specific enough.

Here is how the django code looks like:

```
def get_capabilities(self):
    capabilities_dict = {}
    capabilities_list = ('card', 'module') #Two ManyToMany fields
    capabilities_dict.update(self.barebone.get_capabilities()) 
    # self.barebone.get_capabilities() is the only foreingkey field
    # and serves as the base on which we build the capabilities list.
    for capability in capabilities_list:
        instances = getattr(self, capability).all()
        for instance in instances:
            capabilities = instance.get_capabilities()
            for capability_name in capabilities:
                if capability_name in capabilities_dict:
                    for obj in capabilities[capability_name]:
                        if obj in capabilities_dict[capability_name]:
                            capabilities_dict[capability_name][obj] += capabilities[capability_name][obj]
                        else:
                            capabilities_dict[capability_name][obj] = capabilities[capability_name][obj]
                else:
                    capabilities_dict[capability_name] = capabilities[capability_name]
    return capabilities_dict
```

self.barebone.get_capabilities() looks like this:

```
{'compatible_bus_types': {<BusType: PCI-X>: 1},
 'compatible_storage_interfaces': {<StorageInterface: SATA>: 8},
 'compatible_storage_form_factors': {<StorageFormFactor: 3.5">: 4}}
```

and the function get_capabilities() above returns this:

```
{'compatible_network_connectors': {},
 'compatible_storage_interfaces': {<StorageInterface: SATA>: 8,
                                   <StorageInterface: SAS>: 8},
 'compatible_network_standards': {},
 'compatible_storage_form_factors': {<StorageFormFactor: 3.5">: 4},     
 'compatible_bus_types': {<BusType: PCI-X>: 1},
 'compatible_network_form_factors': {}}
```

Each <> enclosed "inner-keys" are in fact another model instance.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Using `collections.Counter` with a normal dict:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dictc = {}
>>> for d in (dicta, dictb):
    for k, v in d.items():
        dictc[k] = dictc.get(k, Counter()) + Counter(v)
...         
>>> dictc
{'a': Counter({'a2': 2, 'a1': 1}),
 'c': Counter({'c2': 2, 'c1': 1}),
 'b': Counter({'a2': 2, 'b1': 2, 'b2': 2})}
```

or with a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> dictc = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for d in (dicta, dictb):
    for k, v in d.items():
        dictc[k] += Counter(v)
...         
>>> dictc
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
{'a': Counter({'a2': 2, 'a1': 1}),
 'c': Counter({'c2': 2, 'c1': 1}),
 'b': Counter({'a2': 2, 'b1': 2, 'b2': 2})})
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it seems to be verry good for my initial concern. I updated my question because your answer, while quite good, did not fit my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You use nested `dict`s but I think there is an *easier data-structure*: You can take a *tuple* like `('a','a2')` *as key* instead. Your dicts would look like this:

```
dicta = {('a', 'a1'): 1, ('a', 'a2'): 2, ('b', 'b1'): 1, ('b', 'b2'): 2}
dictb = {('b', 'a2'): 2, ('b', 'b1'): 1, ('c', 'c1'): 1, ('c', 'c2'): 2}
```

Accessing the values would work like this:

```
print dicta['a', 'a1']
Out: 1
```

instead of

```
print dicta['a']['a1']
Out: 1
```

To change your data into that structure you can you this function:

```
def unnestdict(dct):
    return { (key1, key2):value 
                         for key1, sub_dct in dct.iteritems()
                             for key2, value in sub_dct.iteritems()}
```

If you use this data structure you can easily use the `Counter`-class from `collections`-module:

```
from collections import Counter

counterC = Counter(dicta) + Counter(dictb)
print counterC
Out: Counter({('b', 'b2'): 2, ('a', 'a2'): 2, ('b', 'b1'): 2, ('b', 'a2'): 2, ('c', 'c2'): 2, ('a', 'a1'): 1, ('c', 'c1'): 1})

dictc = dict(counterC)
print dictc
Out: {('b', 'a2'): 2, ('b', 'b1'): 1, ('c', 'c1'): 1, ('c', 'c2'): 2}
```